# Getting ListView item when clicking "Cell control" like button

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have `ListView` with `Button` in `Cell`. When I am clicking cell's button I want to get current item.

This is ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image x:Name="Image1"  Source="other.png" />
                    <Label TextColor="{StaticResource mainColor}" 
                           Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
                    <Button x:Name="mybtn"                                
                    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference list1}, Path=BindingContext}" 
                    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource CaribGreenPresent}"
                    Text="{Binding AttendanceTypeStatusIdGet, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}">
                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I am clicking on `mybtn`I want to get current item in ViewModel, How can I do that?

This is my ViewModel code

```
private List<Student> _studentList;
public List<Student> StudentList
{
    get { return _studentList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _studentList, value); }
}
```

List screenshot:

[image]

**Edit 1:**
Getting error in ViewModel:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'

This is code

```
//Constructor
public StudentAttendanceListPageViewModel(INavigationService _navigationService):base(_navigationService)
{
    ItemCommand=new DelegateCommand<Student>(BtnClicked);
}

public DelegateCommand<Student> ItemCommand { get; }
public void BtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var item = (Student)btn.CommandParameter;
    // now item points to the Student selected from the list
}
```

Button XAML

```
<Button x:Name="mybtn"                                
BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference list1}, Path=BindingContext}" 
Command="{Binding ItemCommand }" 
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mybtn}}"              
Text="{Binding AttendanceTypeStatusId, Converter={x:StaticResource IDToStringConverter}}">
</Button>
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put the command on the student's view model?

Comment: `ItemCommand`  is inside StudentViewModel only.

Comment: So why don't you just use `this` to get the clicked `StudentViewModel`?

Comment: @Haukinger - I am sorry but I am not understanding at all. Could you pl write it as answer or explain bit more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a command binding:

```
<Page x:Name="ThePage"
  ...>
  <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          ...
          <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path=BindingContext.ItemCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</Page>

// Now in the VM...
ItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<Student>(ButtonClicked);
private void ButtonClicked(Student student)
{
  // Do something with the clicked student...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, do not change the `BindingContext` of your button

```
<Button Clicked="BtnClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" ... />
```

then in your code behind

```
protected void BtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var btn = (Button)sender;
  var item = (Student)btn.CommandParameter;
  // now item points to the Student selected from the list
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but this looks like code behind not Prism.

Comment: How to get modified this item and sync with ViewModel's `List<Student>`

Comment: You can do the same thing with a command if you want to avoid using the code behind.  Either way you are getting a reference to the same item that exists in the ViewModel

Comment: If I will to with command than passing two params might be difficult `object sender, EventArgs args` in DelegateCommand

Comment: you don't need to send two parameters, you would just send the CommandParameter directly with ICommand<Student>

Comment: I am getting error `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<Student>'` pl check Edit1 in my question.

Comment: OR tell me how to sync updated item with ViewModels `List<Student>`.